25 random records but can’t repeat a column value
I tried this
SELECT distinct user_id, rcv_from, apptid 
FROM view.data_all 
where facility like '%dallas%' 
  and rcv_from >= '2020-10-01' 
  and rcv_from <= '2021-09-30' 
ORDER BY RAND( ) Limit 25

Problem is the user_id can’t be duplicated in the data. Has to be 25 users no repeats.
All this data has multiple user, rec date and appts
I can’t seem to get 25 distinct records every time, sometime it’s 18 sometimes it’s 24 a few times has been 25 exactly..
Anyone have a possible solution?
Kevin

This is incorrect if a user and rcv date and appt I’d can appear in 2000 records then distinct cannot guarantee no repeats since all 3 columns are treated as distinct

I can’t seem to get 25 distinct records every time Of course, DISTINCT is applied to the whole row and not to one column only. If The user_id is the same but some other column values differs then these are not distinct rows, and both will be returned. PS. What is MySQL version precisely?

I believe it is 5.3 I understand they are distinct but I am trying to get 25 random re rods that the user isn’t duplicated.

I believe it is 5.3 o_O Execute SELECT VERSION(); and provide the output.

I gave you three duplicate questions with answers highlighting different solutions. The first one is for mysql v8+, the 2nd one can be used with any versions, third one is for mysql v5.7-. Do not use partial aggregation solution suggested in multiple answers as it is against the sql standard and it depends on sql_mode setting if it will work in your mysql.
